# Como pasar parámetros a main

Tags: java, selenium, parametros

¿Como puedo pasar parámetros que están en el pom.xml al main de la clase principal? Si por ejemplo quiero coger la propiedad de argLine, como puedo llevarla al main, y dentro del main, ejecutarlo después?

---

pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore> 
                    **<argLine>-Darg1=7070 -Darg2=9</argLine>**

                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/test/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>

                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>Resource/PageObjectsCommon</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>

                    <groups>test</groups>
                </configuration>
```

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.stream(args).forEach(System.out::println);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <profiles>
            <profile>
               <id>dev</id>
               <properties>
                    <spring.profiles.active>dev</spring.profiles.active>
                    <fileupload.url.base> localhost:8080// </fileupload.url.base>
                </properties>
            </profile>
    <profiles>
```

En la clase que quieras usar algun parametro utiliza:

```
@Value("${fileupload.url.base}")
    private String url;
```

Comment: ¿Es de suponer que el @value es como el javadoc? ¿Habría otro ejemplo mas claro que no fuese con <fileupload.url.base> ?

Comment: Da igual, puedes poner >fileupload.url.base> como <miparametro.numero1> datosparametros </miparametro.numero1>